# How to reset the formArray values to default values ?since form.reset() makes it null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am new to angular and I have a form with these fields.

```
 this.catform = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl('', Validators.required,),
  source: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  event: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  cond:  this.fb.array([this.Cond()], Validators.required)     
});

 Cond() : FormGroup {
return this.fb.group({
  disp : new FormControl(1),
  field: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  ct: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  value: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  ot : 'AND'
});
}
```

After submitting the form, I do the this.catform.reset(), but this resets the "disp" and "ot" to null, and thus makes my form have the values to null. Now when I submit this form again, it is unsuccessful in the backend since those values are null in the form but the backend doesnt accept this creation.So I want these to be as the ones which I have mentioned above, and I don't have these 2 fields in the HTML template, so I cannot edit them from the HTML template.
Please if anyone could suggest some way.

Comment: you can pass an object inside the reset for defaults.

Comment: can you share something in the comments, on passiing this object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the following code into a method. And when you want to reset, just call the method and assign it to this.catform

```
new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required,),
    source: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    event: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    cond:  this.fb.array([this.Cond()], Validators.required)
});
```

Like this:

```
this.catform=this.getFormgroup();

private getFormgroup() {
    return new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required,),
    source: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    event: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    cond:  this.fb.array([this.Cond()], Validators.required)
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried this, but this break the code and gives this error, there is no formControl with source: , my formControl source and event is a dropdown in HTML template, whose options I get in ngOnInIt() hook using a service

Comment: I did some workaround for my source options, i think it's correct. @Srikanth,  thanks